# Choice keys and exception handling

Tags: programming, package-writing, key-value

Recently, I switched a self-written "bundle package" from using `xkeyval` to `keyreader`. One reason for this, beside the backward compatibility, was that the definition of keys is more convenient in keyreader, especially for choicekeys. One thing that is missing tough is the variant `\define@choicekey+`, where faulty user input can be caught by a self-defined macro.
My first, and rather obvious, question is if there is a solution for this in `keyreader`.

However, the more I thought about the problem, the more I wished there was an exception mechanism in LaTeX. As far as I understand it (which admittedly is not so much), in `pgfkeys` (and maybe `ltxkeys`?) there exists something like that when you define handlers for keys in the */error/* tree.

So apart from shoehorning code to fit `pgfkeys` paradigm, do approaches to exceptions in LaTeX exist?

Comment: Do you mean dealing with 'unknown' choices?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes. At least for the part with keyreader ;-)

Comment: *ltxkeys* doesn't use *pgfkeys*-type of handlers. *skeyval* (version 1.0) does use handlers, while retaining *xkeyval* syntax for some of the commands. Well, I will try to answer your question about *keyreader* package.

Answer (score 4):

The plus form of choice key has the syntax

```
\define@choicekey+[<pref>]{<fam>}{<key>}[<bin>]{<nominations>}[<default>]{<f1>}{<f2>}
```

When the user input is found in `<nominations>`, `<f1>` will be executed, otherwise `<f2>` will be called. The command `\krddefinekeys` of *keyreader* package hardwires `<f2>` to `\krd@keyvalerr` because in most cases the user would usually enter an error message in `<f2>`. *pgfkeys* will call `/errors/unknown choice value={<key>}{<value>}` in this case, which is equivalent to `\krd@keyvalerr`.

`<f1>` and `<f2>` are called "functions" in the *xkeyval* package, and "callbacks" in the *keyreader* package.

When you specify the key type `choice`, the command `\krddefinekeys` automatically and always uses the star (`*`) and plus (`+`) variant of `\define@choicekey` internally. So the choice key `align` in

```
\krddefinekeys*[KV]{ebox}[mp@]{% 
  choice/align/center/ 
    center.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfil\let\mp@alignleft\hfil, 
    right.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfill\let\mp@alignleft\relax, 
    left.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\hfill, 
    justified.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\relax
}
```

is equivalent to the following code. This is what is executed internally in defining the key `align`.

```
\define@choicekey*+[KV]{ebox}[mp@]{align}[\krduserinput\krdorder]{%
  center,right,left,justified
}[{center}]{%
  \krd@executealt{#1}{<f1>}%
}{%
  \krd@keyvalerr
}
```

The macro `\krd@keyvalerr` is defined as

```
\protected\def\krd@keyvalerr{%
  \krd@getinnoval
  \@latex@error{Erroneous value '\krd@ival' \MessageBreak for key or 
    option '\XKV@tkey'}{Invalid value for key '\XKV@tkey'.}%
}
```

where `\krd@ival` is the "innocent value" of the key. It is computed by `\krd@getinnoval` and is normally of length 20 "innocent" characters at most. `\krd@keyvalerr` is perhaps the "exception handler" that you refer to. If you like, you can redefine it, but be careful.

The example file of *keyreader* package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\shadowsize
\krddefinekeys*[KV]{ebox}[mp@]{%
  bool/frame/true;
  bool/shadow/true;
  cmd/framecolor/black;
  cmd/shadecolor/white;
  cmd/shadowcolor/gray;
  cmd/framesize/.4pt;
  cmd/boxsize/.1\columnwidth;
  cmd/shadowsize/1pt;
  choice/align/center/
    center.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfil\let\mp@alignleft\hfil,
    right.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfill\let\mp@alignleft\relax,
    left.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\hfill,
    justified.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\relax
  ;
}
\savevaluekeys[KV]{ebox}{frame,framecolor,framesize}
\krdpresetkeys[KV]{ebox}{%
  frame,framecolor=black,shadecolor=white,framesize=0.5pt,boxsize,align
}
\krdpostsetkeys[KV]{ebox}{%
  shadow=\usevalue{frame},shadowcolor=\usevalue{framecolor}!40,
  shadowsize=\usevalue{framesize}*4
}
\newcommand*\ebox[2][]{%
  \krdsetkeys[KV]{ebox}{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \ifmp@frame
    \fboxrule=\dimexpr\mp@framesize\relax
  \else
    \fboxrule=0pt
  \fi
  \ifmp@shadow
    \shadowsize=\dimexpr\mp@shadowsize\relax
  \else
    \shadowsize=0pt
  \fi
  \setbox0=\hbox{%
    \fcolorbox{\mp@framecolor}{\mp@shadecolor}{%
      \hbox to\mp@boxsize{%
        \mp@alignright #2\mp@alignleft
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \hskip\shadowsize
  \color{\mp@shadowcolor}%
  \rule[-\dp0]{\wd0}{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
  \llap{\raisebox{\shadowsize}{\box0\hskip\shadowsize}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ebox[shadecolor=brown]{ebox1}
\ebox[framecolor=magenta,boxsize=2cm,align=right]{ebox2}
\ebox[shadow=false,framesize=1pt,framecolor=red,boxsize=1.5cm,align=left]{ebox3}
\ebox[framesize=1pt,framecolor=green,shadowcolor=blue]{ebox4}
\ebox[frame=false,shadow,shadowcolor=yellow,framesize=.5pt]{ebox5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am submitting version 0.5 of *keyreader* to CTAN. The syntax for `\krddefinekeys` is extended to meet your need:

```
\krddefinekeys[<pref>]{<fam>}[<mp>]{
  ord/<key>/<dft>/<f1>;
  cmd/<key>/<dft>/<f1>;
  bool/<key>/<dft>/<f1>;
  bool+/<key>/<dft>/<f1>/<f2>;
  choice/<key>/<dft>/<nominations>/<f1>;
  choice+/<key>/<dft>/<nominations>/<f1>/<f2>;
}
```

Here `<f2>` is, hopefully, the "handler" you wanted. This is now in the package but you won't find it in the documentation yet.

Example:

```
\krddefinekeys*[KV]{fam}[mp@]{%
  ord/keya/default-a/\def\x##1{#1*##1};
  bool/keyb/true/;
  bool+/keyc/true/\def\valueaccepted{#1}/\@latexerr{Invalid value '#1' for keyc}\@ehd;
  cmd/keyd/black;
  choice/keye/blue/green,blue,red,cyan/\def\emptycallback{};
  choice+/keyf/center/
    center.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfil\let\mp@alignleft\hfil,
    right.do=\let\mp@alignright\hfill\let\mp@alignleft\relax,
    left.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\hfill,
    justified.do=\let\mp@alignright\relax\let\mp@alignleft\relax
    //
    \let\mp@alignright\hfil\let\mp@alignleft\hfil
    \@@warning{Invalid value for keyf; 'center' assumed}
  ;
}
```

Comment: I still did not read `keyreader`s code, but I have a feeling that `\krd@keyvalerr` is not only used by `keyreader`s choicekeys. Since I use `\krdProcessOptions` to set the keys, it seems that there is no easy way to define an individual Catch for my choice key; some kind of switch statement on `\XKV@tkey` in `\krd@keyvalerr` would be necessary; this is uncomfortable (but would also be needed in a handler for `pgfkeys` `/error` tree?). Putting that global macro in the **else** part of `xkeyval` `+`-variant just takes away a great Catch variant. BTW: What do the callbacks of choice keys do?

Comment: What you're suggesting is in effect a key type `choice+`. That will allow the user to specify the error for each choice key. That is possible but to what end?

Comment: Why not? The programmer may fall back to a standard choice for the value of the key and only throw a warning if the user supplied a value not defined in the choice key. I think there are many applications that neither you nor me think about, but I want just do that. My point is that it is possible in `xkeyval`, but not in `keyreader`, and I for one miss it.

Comment: OK, that and more will be provided in the next release of *keyreader* package.

Comment: All right, very nice :-) Thank you.